# How to decide if the URL is local file path or Remote file path

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, filepath, nsfilemanager

I am getting a scenario where the file may be uploaded to the server so that time the path will be like file://some path starting with /somepath .../ which i convert using NSURL urlWithFilePath to server.

Once the server have the file there is a mechanism where I download that contents and get the remote path like http:// for the same file.

Now decision is when I tap on the image I want to decide to open this in full screen , but before that have to device whether to apply [NSURL URLWithString] or [NSURL fileURLPath].

Any guess how to detect this before applying to open image correctly.

Comment: You can't have a `file:` URL to a remote server. It's only for local files.

Comment: thanks rmaddy but thats not my query answer , I want to decide from the string path stored in DB either at the time of upload or download of this info if its remote or local path.

Comment: If the string has a scheme, use `URLWithString`. If not, use `fileURLWithPath`.

Comment: Can you give example what you meant by scheme.

Comment: you can check whether imageName have `http://` then you can apply one of those

Comment: http:, file:, ftp:, mailto:, tel:, etc.

Comment: Okay its better i write a category in NSString class to return URL and do this check if it has http,https return [nsurl urlwithstring] else return [nsurl fileurlwithpath]. Thanks Guys

Comment: Yes you can do that way also, I guess you are storing imageName in string in DB which is either `file://` or `http://`. so you can check that string `contains http://`.

Comment: Check if this answer I posted is exactly as we discussed and mark check so others can get help from this. :)

Answer (score -2):

Adding a Category "NSString+URL.m" Class

```
-(NSURL*)url
{
   NSURL *myURL;
 if ([self.lowercaseString hasPrefix:@"http://"] || [self.lowercaseString hasPrefix:@"https://"] || [self.lowercaseString hasPrefix:@"file://"]) {
    myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self];
}
else 
 {
    //Default consider it file url path 
    myURL = [NSURL fileUrlWithPath:self];
 }
return myURL;
}
```

Comment: No, this is incorrect. If it has any scheme (including `file:`), you need to use `URLWithString`. Only use `fileURLWithPath` if the string represents a file path. A file path won't have any URL scheme. And a string like `www.google.com` is not a valid URL.

Comment: file: ???? is always local file not remote file. And check my question , i am dealing with only local file path or remote path http:// or file:// , the other what you say in invalid url is just error check condition to avoid returning nil.

Comment: If you have a string such as `file://some/path/to/a/file.txt` then you must create the `NSURL` using `URLWithString:`. If you have a string such as `/some/path/to/a/file.txt` then you must use `fileURLWithPath:`.

Comment: ok understand I'll update my post answer to accept it better way

Comment: This will fail if the url has other scheme than `http`/`https`/`file`. Also this will fail for invalid url strings that happen to start with the schema prefix you handle there.

Comment: Okay understand but the business case is to get / receive only https, htts and /local path of the Doc folder/